# How to select desired button in JSP from request object

Tags: java, jsp, button

I have three buttons on HTML page like below in my form

```
<input type="submit" value="Insert" name="btn"  />
<input  type="submit" value="Update" name="btn" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete" name="btn" />
```

and in JSP page I want if I click on insert, it insert data into database and so on..

I use following if block but it does not work (I check without if, it works and data inserted to table)

```
<%if("Insert" == request.getParameter("btn")){
DBFaculty ins =new DBFaculty();
r = ins.insertTable(te);
if(r == 1){
  %>
  <h3 style="color: lightblue">Data insert in to table</h3>
  <% }else {%>
  <h3 style="color:lightcoral">Fail</h3>
  <% } 
}
%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because this `if` block is never executed, strings are compared using `equals` method.

```
<%if("Insert".equals(request.getParameter("btn"))){
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `equals()` in the if, instead of `==`, to compare the strings.